# How to refresh recyclerview when data changed or removed in sqlite android fragments?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I am storing title, thumbnail, id in SQLite android and displaying in a recyclerview.
i have created all methods i.e. getting data,addition, deletion and updation in my sqlite helper class and calling these methods in my fragment android.

but the problem is when i delete or add items to sqlite its not refreshing.
yes i defined `adapter.notifydatasetChanged()` in fragment class.

example:

this is my sqlite openhelper class:

1. `public List<dataModel> getDatabase();`
2. `public void addData(dataModel data);`
3. `public void deleteData(dataModel data);`

I am calling these methods in fragment class and i am assigning 
 `getDatabase()` to List in a fragment.

Thanks in advance.
Edit 1:

```
public class LightFragment extends Fragment {

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
FloatingActionButton addLightTitle,allLightsOff;
ArrayList<LightTitle> lightTitle;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

EditText edxLightName;
Button btnLightName;

SQLiteDatabase  db;
LDbHelper lHelper;
ArrayList<LightPojo> mLightPojos = new ArrayList<>();
LightRecyclerView li;


@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public LightFragment(Context mContext) {

    lHelper = new LDbHelper(mContext);

}

public LightFragment() {
}





@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_light, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mLightPojos = lHelper.getLightData();

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.light_frag);
    addLightTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_add_light_title);
    allLightsOff = view.findViewById(R.id.fab_off_all_lights);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
    mLightPojos = lHelper.getLightData();
           li = new LightRecyclerView(getContext(),mLightPojos);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(li);
    li.notifyDataSetChanged();

    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(),mRecyclerView,new ClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            Log.d("BT","clicked" + mLightPojos.get(position).getName());
            //toast("clicked" + position );

            if (!mLightPojos.get(position).isClicked()){
                ImageView lightPopUp = view.findViewById(R.id.row_light_thumbnail);
                lightPopUp.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_on);
                //DrawableCompat.setTint(lightPopUp.getDrawable().mutate(), ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.white));
                toast(mLightPojos.get(position).getName() + "light on");
                Log.d("BT","clicked" + mLightPojos.get(position).isClicked());
                //mLightPojos.get(position).setClicked(true);
                LightPojo pojo = new LightPojo(mLightPojos.get(position).getId(),R.drawable.light_on,true);
                lHelper.upDateState(pojo);
            }else {
                ImageView lightPopUp = view.findViewById(R.id.row_light_thumbnail);
                toast(mLightPojos.get(position).getName() + "light off");
                lightPopUp.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_off);
                //DrawableCompat.setTint(lightPopUp.getDrawable().mutate(), ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorAccent));
                Log.d("BT","clicked" + mLightPojos.get(position).isClicked());
                //mLightPojos.get(position).setClicked(false);
                //lHelper.upDateState(position,R.drawable.light_off,false);
                LightPojo pojo = new LightPojo(mLightPojos.get(position).getId(),R.drawable.light_off,false);
                lHelper.upDateState(pojo);
            }



        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, final int position) {
            toast("long pressed at " + position);
            final Dialog eDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            eDialog.setContentView(R.layout.edit_light_name);
            //EditText editLightName = eDialog.findViewById(R.id.edit_light_name_edx);
            //final String editedLightName = editLightName.getText().toString();
            Button deleteLightName = eDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete_light_name);
            Button updateLightName = eDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_update_light_name);
            eDialog.show();
           // eDialog.setTitle("Edit light name");



            updateLightName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //lightTitle.set(position,editLightName.getText().toString());
                    //Log.d("BT",editedLightName);
                    EditText editLightName = eDialog.findViewById(R.id.edit_light_name_edx);

                    //lightTitle.set(position,new LightTitle(editLightName.getText().toString(),false));
                    LightPojo pojo = new LightPojo(mLightPojos.get(position).getId(),editLightName.getText().toString());
                    lHelper.editName(pojo);
                    lHelper.getLightData();
                    li.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    eDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            deleteLightName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //lightTitle.remove(position);
                    LightPojo pojo = new LightPojo(mLightPojos.get(position).getId());
                    lHelper.delete(pojo);
                    li.notifyItemChanged(position);
                    //li.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    eDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


        }
    }));

    addLightTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //toast("clicked fab button");

            //LightTitleDialog titleDialog = new LightTitleDialog();
            //titleDialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),"title");
            final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            mDialog.setTitle("Add light name");
            mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_light_title);
            edxLightName = mDialog.findViewById(R.id.edt_light_title);
            btnLightName = mDialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_add_title);
            mDialog.show();

            btnLightName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //toast("Add light");
                    if (edxLightName.getText().length() != 0){
                        String newLightName = edxLightName.getText().toString();
                        //lightTitle.add(new LightTitle(newLightName,false));
                        //add(newLightName,R.id.utilities_thumbnail,false);
                        lHelper.insertData(newLightName,R.drawable.light_off,false);
                        li.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                    }else {
                        toast("Please enter light name");
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

Comment: You only modify the database before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`. You never update the `ArrayList` for the `Adapter`, though.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand.

Comment: Your `Adapter` – `LightRecyclerView` – is creating `View`s from the `mLightPojos` `ArrayList`. `LightRecyclerView` doesn't know anything about what's in your database, only about the items in `mLightPojos`. When you delete or update something from the database, it does not automatically get deleted from or updated in `mLightPojos`. You have to handle that, before you notify.

Comment: Thank you my problem solved @MikeM.

Comment: @MikeM. I was having the same problem. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I found that I have to explicitly change ArrayList when clicked. apart from database update.

After updating values into the SQLite call adapter methods for internally updating values. you no need to get SQLite data every time when data updated.

Answer (score 0):

Please call below methods once you update the data model.

```
 adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

This will update the Adapter about removing an element from the list.

Answer (score 0):

After updating your data model call `adapter.notifydatasetChanged()` from Fragment or Activity(whatever you are using). Then recyclerView will be updated.